# How to get the value of a variable in CCK from Devel?

Tags: 6, debugging

I am using a custom .tpl file to theme teasers, and I am having trouble with the value of a variable returning `true` even when apparently there is no value inside (`$picture`). I would like to see what exactly this variable contains.

How do I leverage Devel to view this variable without having to `var_dump()`? Currently, the teasers are inside a view which is inside a block on the home page.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned after enabling the [Dev module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), you can use `dpm($variable);` to get a detailed graphical listing of the array values.